# How to run a audio file again and again in ios sdk

Tags: ios7

```
SystemSoundID soundID6; // declaration    
NSURL *gamePlayMusic = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle
mainBundle]pathForResource:@"song1" ofType:@"wav"]];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)Music,&soundID6);    
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID6); //running of music
```

may I know what to code to run this music again after it finish/complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Add AVKit.framework. 
2.create a global webview object like UIWebView* audioPlayerView; 
3.create a button action for playing audio file
4.your mp3 file add in to your bundel.

  -(IBAction)playAudioFile:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your file name" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [audioPlayerView loadRequest:request];
        [audioPlayerView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:audioPlayerView];
    }
```